# Is a showcase of preambles off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Would it be off-topic to have a question where people can showcase good preambles for some specific purpose (like assignments, books, lecture notes, letters, articles etc.)? I am thinking about a topic like *[Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends)*, but where you can show off concrete preambles that are useful for this and that particular purpose (obviously, we would need different questions for each purpose). I am not thinking about a topic like *[Best practice on organising your preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40760/best-practice-on-organising-your-preamble)*, which is more concerned with the theory of overall preamble design. Also, *[What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex)* is not what I am thinking of either, since it is for showcasing individual packages, not full preambles. There is currently (as far as I can see) no topic here that matches my suggestion, which might be because it would be considered opinion-based.

I expect a lot of comments arguing that it is impossible to create one preamble that solves all problems, that it is better if people sit down and learn TeX themselves and find out which packages *they* need. The *reality* is that many people never learn to write proper TeX at all, precisely because they are left alone in the vast jungle of classes and packages, many of which are obsolete, poorly written, unnecessary, do not work together, or break core functionality. Furthermore, there is an equally outdated collection of manuals on the Internet that promote bad coding practice and wrong solutions. As a result, a lot of people get started on TeX by taking over preambles from others, which are filled with precisely the mentioned kind of packages. For instance, I have found LaTeX preambles on the Internet that still use `\documentstyle`.

In my opinion, a lot of people would benefit from a topic on this page that showed up-to-date, well-written and well-documented preambles, created and maintained by some of the TeX oracles in here. They cannot and should not contain solutions to all problems, but should include the standard packages that many people will need in this particular situation. The usual Stack Exchange voting system would naturally regulate such a topic, the best preambles coming out on top.

Comment: As far as I have been taught on TeX-SX, putting information as showcase online makes people even lazier hence for the sanity of future generations I really don't want to have yet another source of confusion. For proof, see the LaTeX wiki. As much as I usually take the side of the newcomers, I would be the first to admit that people are lazy. If they just read this site for an hour about the packages they have been using since the last two decades we wouldn't have your second paragraph. One particular example on TeXample.net and we had at least 20 questions about it here.

Comment: The problem is that looking through all these packages is a very large amount of work for a newcomer, and this makes the initial TeX learning curve even more steep. When I started using LaTeX a few years ago, it would have been very helpful for me to have a general template that showed to me which standard packages you should always load. I'm thinking of `amsmath` and friends, `microtype`, `babel`, `inputenc`, `fontenc`, `memoir`(or `KOMA-script`), `hyperref`, `csquotes`, `siunitx`, `graphicx`. For papers with theorems, add `cleveref`, `varioref`, and `ntheorem`.

Comment: For your examples, if people switch to Lua- or Xe- they should drop the `fontenc`, `inputenc` and switch to fontspec also `microtype` causes problems in certain cases. `babel` works but `polyglossia` sometimes a better choice. What about `mathtools` instead of `amsmath`. Even the location where you place `hyperref` is an art. Hence, it is not that straightforward to say *this is an ideal preamble* and works under every condition. It will work only specific to that  particular preamble.

Comment: @percusse Obviously, such issues would have to be taken into account. For instance, preamble is filled with `\ifluatex` (I never you XeTeX). Also, I am pretty sure that you should load both `mathtools` and `amsmath`, as I usually do. The fact that such issues exist is IMO precisely why people need templates that load the "right" packages (the ones the author finds right) in the correct locations. People can then add special packages (like `listings`) if they need to, or stick to the template. It is possible to make good templates that solve not all, but *many* problems.

Comment: And the good thing is that it is Stack Exchange, so there can be several answers to the same question. And there is a surprisingly general consensus about which packages should be loaded and which are obsolete. Nobody in their right mind advises people to load `graphics` instead of `graphicx`, for instance.

Comment: `mathtools` loads `amsmath` already so you don't need to load it. See what I mean?

Comment: Impossible, should not be done. i can't express how mnuch i am against this idea. Taking into account all that is to be thought of, the answer will have an incredible amount of information; *the wall of confusion*. Who is to climb that wall?

Comment: I have seen documents don't need `amsmath`, nor `siunitx`, nor any other package. Nor any other package.

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion

Comment: Okay, so everything is relative. Let us use the same reasoning on the school system: There are cultures in the world that do not have math; therefore, I do not want our schools to teach math. Similarly for religion, social sciences, and literature. Also, there are non-literal cultures, so there is no rational reason why schools should teach us how to read and write. In fact, anything that schools teach children can be considered biased one way or another. So let us just close those schools and start a wiki where people can find information for themselves if they want to.

Comment: Ask your indian friends about the old colonial school system. Some might indeed prefer a world without schools. The point is that we have the *de facto* position of TeX related best-pratice source. When something appears here it will be picked up by some and if it works for their initial four five documents they will use it for life. And **that** is exactly what happened years ago and that's why you have your second paragraph.

Comment: @Gaussler -- no, you should *not* load both `amsmath` and `mathtools`.  `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, and if you want to add an option to `amsmath` (such as `fleqn`), and you happen to load `amsmath` *after* `mathtools`, you won't get the result you expect.  if you're a newbie, that can be extremely confusing.  what is needed instead, is a good tutorial on *how* to load packages -- what they do, which are interrelated, and what is the benefit of *a* over *b*.  oh, what is *really* needed are users *who read documentation* and don't expect to find ready-made preambles.

Comment: It might not be off-topic. But I don't think it is a good idea. A collection such as this will just run risk of becoming one of the pages where people go and copy and paste a preamble without thinking about it. The problem with that approach is that just because people have a preamble that doesn't mean they know what to do with it. People might load `cleveref` with all its bells and whistles and still write `see equation (4) in Theorem 3` out by hand. So a skilfully crafted preamble (percusse is absolutely right, writing one is an art) is not the solution to the problem.

Comment: Additionally, you would have to create lots of "example preambles" for all sorts of different applications. I firmly believe that loading a package just for the sake of (loading) it, and then not using it, is counter-productive to say the least. You probably shouldn't load `pgfplots` if you don't need to plot anything, and if you don't write maths you probably don't need `mathtools`. Another problem is that sometimes (often) there are more packages for one job, and an in-depth discussion about the (dis)advantages is needed to decide which one to use.

Comment: @moewe Well, wasn't that part of the suggestion already? Different preambles for different purposes. The amount of work required is not a good counterargument IMO. If you read my comments above closely, you will notice that I suggested loading a standard set of packages by default, then adding below that people might want to load, say, `pgfplots` in this and that case in order to be able to draw graphs, and *only* in this case.

Comment: I've never in my life loaded `siunitx` or `ntheorem` except in examples for this site. Not once have I written a document in which they would have been of any use. `hyperref` should NOT be loaded by default, in my opinion. By default, it will draw coloured boxes around stuff. Many people print documents. Coloured boxes print badly in black-and-white (the most common case) and are distracting (in all cases). And `hyperref` causes other problems which can be easily avoided by not loading it if you don't need it.  I prefer `fancyref` to `cleverref`: for some workflows, it is superior.

Comment: When I ran a workshop last year, I asked [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237100/which-packages-should-i-recommend-to-postgraduates-in-different-academic-discipl). Note that I suggest a very short list of 'almost always' packages. (Some may well argue it is nonetheless too long.) This list assumes that pdfTeX is used, since the workshops were limited to that engine. The same packages could not be included in a more generic list.

Comment: Yes it was part of the question, I just wanted to put emphasis on the fact that you are potentially end up with *a lot* of different preambles. A list that is not only hard to maintain, but also to navigate. If by the "then adding below ..." part you mean that a detailed discussion of the pros and cons of different packages for the same job follows, I would be all for, but from what I read it was more of a "load this for that job" list. Also what would a list of standard packages be? Do you need `babel`? `hyperref`? `ntheorem`?

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to branch in the preamble with `\ifluatex`, if that is what you suggested above (I'm not entirely sure). A user should understand the preamble and every line should actually do something. You run the risk of amassing a huge preamble with all sort of logic and branching that it hard to suss out. Finally, I would like to repeat the point of my first comment: Just because you load a package that doesn't mean you know how to use it. An example preamble would need to also come with a showcase document that shows how you use all the fancy stuff you have requested.

Comment: ... Simply writing "for quotation marks" as a comment next to `\usepackage{csquotes}` is useless if people don't know how to turn characters active, or that they need to use `\enquote{foo}`.

Comment: I think a collection of high-quality preambles is a great aid to novices. But TeX.sx is probably not the best place to showcase it. Better to do it on a separate website (i.e., like the LaTeX font catalogue).

Comment: @moewe, to me, it still seems your major argument is "too much work for the creator of the preamble". Can't you leave that problem to the creator? FYI, I have previously distributed preamble templates at my university, with extensive documentation (like "write `\csquotes{...}` to make a quote"), explaining what *every single little stupid detail* did, plus *many* examples. Took perhaps a few hours to do. As for `\ifluatex`, I referred to what I did in *my own* preamble. For an example preamble, I would probably create separate versions for pdfTeX, XeTeX and LuaTeX.

Comment: However, my advise to newcomers is (as long as their languages are written with the extended Latin alphabet) is to stick to pdfTeX in the beginning. Hence I would probably only write one for that engine for the time being and perhaps comment on what you could change for the modern engines. In general, my example preamble was praised and has gained quite a bit use by now.

Comment: And yes, I admit I made the error to load both `mathtools` and `amsmath`. I should probably change that, but unless you want to use `leqno`, it should not be a major bug.

Comment: @cfr, it is a matter of one option to get `hyperref` to stop drawing rectangles everywhere. My advise is to always load it with those settings. As for `siunitx`, this is perhaps not strictly necessary, but I consider it useful for practically all kinds of documents. Even if it's a novel I'm writing, `\num{...}` would still come in handy. On the other hand, I would not always load `cleveref`; but I would always have commented code in my preamble that I could uncomment in order to activate it.

Comment: My main point is not the amount of work, though I admit that that also plays into it: I would expect these preambles to be maintained properly. My main point is more that people who blindly copy and paste ignore comments in the preamble or don't read everything. In some cases you will need very long comments to explain the use of a package as well as viable alternatives and known incompatibilities. This will bloat the preamble and might discourage people from reading the comments. They will end up with a huge preamble using only a fraction of the features they could use.

Comment: I think that one should only load packages one needs. As such the loading of each package ought to be a conscious decision. If you simply dump packages into your preamble you are probably not going to know if you need all of them; chances are you don't even know if your document would look any different if you removed anything. I'm all for questions directed at novices such as "I need to add a bibliography to my document, what do I need to do?" if the answers explain different ways and highlight (dis)advantages of the approaches. But I'm against covering users in packages.

Comment: @Gaussler But `hyperref` causes complications. It isn't just a matter of the boxes. If you are going to print in black-and-white (or even colour), it just introduces easily avoidable complexities and problems.

Comment: @cfr Like what?

Comment: @cfr For the record, the boxes `hyperref` shows in the pdf are not printed. ;-)

Comment: I have thought a pretty lot above this issue, it started quite a while ago. Get a cup of tea and a silent environment and let your brain do all the work. Won't take long till you notice you are turning in circles. It is just impossible to make this approach properly. You need to learn how to drive a bike before driving a bike. Same for nuclear power plants, you need to know how to run it. You even have to learn how to hold a hammer properly. Be aware of what you are doing. Learn stuff.

Comment: @Johannes_B Easy tiger... it's just a preamble

Comment: @percusse I see it in the light of *templates* (as some might call it), it is just the same approach. You know my feelings about *templates* ;-)

Comment: Good Lord, I even got a downvote for this. Please realise that I didn't *open* such a topic and have no intention of doing so, seeing the reactions in here. I made this question because I thought that it was a very important *discussion* and a matter of principle. And seeing how passionate some people are about this issue, and how many people have participated, I think the *discussion* was both appropriate and necessary. You can appreciate this discussion whether you agree with me or not.

Comment: @Gaussler I have seen too many questions arising from a preamble/template that is posted somewhere and promoted as good, while it is not. That is why [Template Confusion](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion) started, but the discussion has not yet started off. Still some bits and pieces missing.

Comment: @Johannes_B, exactly, because templates found randomwhere can be promoted as good without any discussion and without the user having any chance to distinguish right from wrong. On the contrary, templates posted on Stack Exchange could be up- or downvoted, discussed, praised, and criticised in the comments. And some of the best TeXnicians in the world would take part in this process.

Comment: I agree with @sean that SE is the wrong place to put that kind of information. But i agree that users are searching for templates. And i also agree that some measures have to take place. Lot's of points have been made that would have been made at the template confusion stuff.

Comment: I suspect none of the best TeXnicians in the world have a preamble "template" that they rely on. I certainly have a "system" in terms of how I generally load packages, probably similar to the "best practice" question you linked to. A philosophy about how to load seems more useful than a list for 30+ different templates for people to unthinkingly copy. As for package loading itself, there's this pexperimental package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pkgloader?lang=en) that you might find interesting.

Comment: @Gaussler Note that down/up votes on Meta don't have the same meaning as on the main site. On the main site, they indicate quality. Here they indicate agreement or disagreement. (Although most people don't vote that way on this meta, I don't think. But some do and generally you shouldn't take it as a criticism of the question *qua* question because it probably isn't.)

Comment: @cfr, I know, but I am trying to change that tendency; people must learn to be able to judge the *question* rather than my personal *opinion*. If people have such deeply rooted, emotional opinions about this issue, the greater the reason to discuss it. As for the *quality* of my question, note that essentially all counterargumenst that people have come up with were mentioned in *the question itself*. Doesn't that count as a thought-through, well-formulated question?

Comment: @Gaussler For the record, it was not I who down-voted ;).

Comment: @cfr -- Is that what voting means here? (I rarely frequent meta.)  I upvoted this question simply because I thought it was a fair question to ask. I upvote the answers if I agree with them (I'm actually far stingier here on the answers compared to the main site), but the questions I have always treated (I suppose) more like how I treat questions on the main site.

Comment: @jon That's what I've seen said. But, really, who knows what anything means on Meta?

Answer (score 27):

Such a question would be clearly *on topic* but should be closed for other reasons (too broad) or (opinion based). This is generally true of any such "showcase" question (despite the fact that one or two have been left to stand).

But aside from general concerns about showcase questions, suggesting preambles would be a really bad idea. One of the more common problems we see is people just collecting ever larger preambles loading packages they don't need, specifying packages multiple times, and generally accumulating complexity and fragility for no gain.  We see this even in the suggested preamble in the comments under the question, where specifying both `amsmath` and `mathtools` just slows things down at best and potentially causes errors if either of them is specified with package options.

A beginner should simply start with

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

and add packages or change the document class *if they need* some feature.

I think any list of "off the shelf" preambles would just promote bad practice.

Comment: For monoglot English contexts, maybe. But if somebody is immediately going to try writing about gwdihŵs in Y Tŷ Gwyn, then it is not going to work out very well.

Comment: @cfr yes exactly! but a high voted preamble answer that has `\userpackage[welsh]{babel}` isn't going to work out too well if it gets block copied into lots of German documents. People should start out small and add what they need, not start with everything and remove things when they get weird package interactions.

Comment: On the contrary, I think a preamble template should always load `babel` (at least if it is for pdfTeX) and have language information in the options of `\documentstyle`. A comment should then indicate something like "Here you choose the main language of the document". In an example preamble I distribute at my university, I load first English and then Danish, with a comment saying very clearly that the *last* language will be the main language of the document. I think I managed to avoid confusion.

Comment: Also, I think I would advise people to start with `memoir` instead of `article`.

Comment: @Gaussler memoir is a good class but people should realise they are using a non standard class and use it once they are familiar with the basics. Some would suggest Koma classes, to which same answer applies. A beginner is best to stick to a standard class, so the experience matches documentation such as the latex book, and the syntax and available commands match what commonly available in journal submission classes, rather than starting with a big class like memoir and then having to learn what you can not do in other contexts.

Comment: @Gaussler posting templates with comments saying how they should be adjusted _simply does not work_ if you put `\usepacakge[danish]{babel}% specify the main language of the document` then people will copy _exactly_ that. The whole point of such a template is for people to copy it without reading documentation, so you can not be surprised if that is what they do, Witness the number of _final_ documents that load lipsum package , or use the `[draft]` option and or other bits of code only ever intended to be in an example.

Comment: Oh, I agree. I only really meant that even this non-preamble is only going to work in some cases. If you're teaching this in a certain context, you can give them the necessary Babel bit for that context. But that won't work here because there is no shared linguistic context.

Comment: @Gaussler If you are telling them about options to pass `\documentstyle` then you are definitely telling them wrong!

Comment: @cfr You got me there. I assume you know what I meant. ;-)

Comment: `s/really/really super awful mega/` This alone -- this concept of the 'inherited preamble' -- is the number one reason those not 'in the know' seem to hold TeX in contempt. Showcasing such a practice would not only normalize it further, but promote it.

Comment: @SeanAllred I learnt LaTeX from a book. I didn't even know what a preamble was to ask anybody for one ;). In retrospect, maybe ignorance did me a favour: I knew so little about it, it didn't even occur to me to seek this kind of thing. I just followed the instructions in the book. (I knew one person using it who told me that I didn't want to learn it and shouldn't try.)

Comment: @SeanAllred As far as I agree about the good words, the *reality* is that people already get started on TeX by taking over bad preambles from others. Even if it were better if everyone started from scratch, this is not going to happen no matter what we do. The only way I can see to counter this bad tendency is to provide new users with better templates.

Comment: "templates" -- *There's that word! That infernal word!* Even if that were the case, the SE platform would not be the place for such a terrible trove. We shouldn't spend time working on something that would damage the community. Rather, we should spend time developing *good*, *visible*, and *ever-current* learning materials for newcomers.

Comment: Where is @barbara? How did this start off of its own? This is amazing. *#FascinatedUserInFrontOfTheScreen*

Comment: @Johannes_B -- barbara has been trying to get some work done.  she has two days in which to clear off old (but still valuable) stuff from a machine that will soon be unplugged, before it's lost forever.  (includes the archives of pre-1990 tugboat.)  this discussion is making her head spin!

Comment: @barbarabeeton No need to rush :-) Save the tugboat articles

Answer (score 11):

Allow me to contribute a few concrete examples of hidden gems of preamble art

[Beamer not compiling presentation properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206987/beamer-not-compiling-presentation-properly)

[Sharelatex 'swallows' 80 pages of my work when compiling pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188114/sharelatex-swallows-80-pages-of-my-work-when-compiling-pdf)

[Using 'caption' package with 'thesis' class - undefined control sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106201/using-caption-package-with-thesis-class-undefined-control-sequence)

[Thesis class error Extra } or forgotten \endgroup on second compile (not first) in float caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107164/thesis-class-error-extra-or-forgotten-endgroup-on-second-compile-not-first)

and many many more (please keep adding if you remember more)

---

Instead have a look at this old question which is kind of what you might have in mind and see the answers gently saying <sup>*noooooooooo, doooon't dooo thisssssss*</sup>

[Good LaTeX preambles for math thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34128/good-latex-preambles-for-math-thesis)

Comment: +1 For your second example which loads the `lipsum` package, since that should only be used for example dummy text and not in a real document.

Comment: @AndrewCashner Ever looked into the `turabian` class? http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/turabian

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't have lipsum loaded. The point I tried to make is how ridiculously haphazard it is. @Johannes_B You are developing an unhealthy dislike to templates. They are not all evil. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, all showcase questions are off-topic. Citing [the help center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

I understand that the view of this community is slightly different and we tend to twist the rules, in sake of usefulness. I can understand how exhaustive lists of all possible (useful) answers is useful, like in
[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)
[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex)
[3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/782/what-are-the-available-documentclass-types-and-their-uses)
[4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/782/what-are-the-available-documentclass-types-and-their-uses)
[5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode). However, **these are not showcase questions**, and while voting can be subjective on them, there are attempts to make the available information objective, for instance by creating a template for the answers, as in [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides). The idea of a showcase being helpful seems at least weird to me, as they can hardly be objective.

Comment: But then we do tolerate the [`big-list`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) questions, of which some (especially highly-voted and -viewed ones) also fit this bill. I for one would be sad to see any of those go. In the light of this "double standard" retreating to "the rules", seems a bit like cheating here.

Comment: @moewe I know about this. It is unfortunate. The problem is, only very few of these IMHO carry any value. I also voted to close many of them.

Comment: I think many of these questions are actually very useful (even if they deviate from the normal Q&A scheme a bit). Given that apparently the general consensus is that we decide on a case-by-case basis whether such a question is valuable, I think there more important point here is to discuss whether a showcase of preambles is "valuable" (whatever that may mean). You are correct if we talk about the rules, but *de facto* other things seem to play into the discussion as well.

Comment: @moewe My opinion is that this one would be completely useless. Of the big-list questions, it's not the showcases that are useful, it's the exhaustive lists that are: Editors/IDEs, books, math alphabets, document classes.

Comment: I actually quite like the showcases as well. Although I agree that of "hard value" are probably only the questions you mention. I also agree that a "showcase of preambles" especially as Gaussler seems to imagine and intend it to work is not useful (and maybe even counterproductive or outright dangerous).

Comment: @moewe I tried to make the answer more clear about the point of "big-list" vs. "showcase".

Comment: Up to a point I agree with you there as well. Answers to showcase questions can't be objectively judged. Still, for nice (maybe not useful, but *nice* and beautiful) results such as [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1319/35864) I'm willing to risk a bit of hypocrisy on my stance on this topic. For a preamble showcase, on the other hand, I'm all for applying the rule rigorously, for reasons see the discussion below the question above.

Comment: @moewe A dose of hypocrisy a day, keeps the SO mods away :P

Comment: @moewe -- "dangerous" is the operative word here.  although not life-threatening, inappropriate preambles can be very expensive, especially when submitted for publication to an organization that takes its editorial function seriously.  and that raises the costs for everybody; higher production costs engender higher subscription costs (or lowered quality, or, even worse, both).  it's sometimes enough to make one cry.